# Can't Run Gephi 0.9.2 On Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, openjdk

I've downloaded gephi-0.9.2-linux.tar.bz to my Ubuntu 19.04 laptop.

I have three different OpenJDK versions installed: 8, 11, and 13:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives --list

java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1111       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.13.0-openjdk-amd64      1211       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.13.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

I can switch between versions using:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives --set java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Nothing happens if I switch to JDK 8 and run the gephy Bash shell.  No messages, no errors, no startup icons.  The command prompt comes back in the terminal.

If I switch to either 11 or 13 I see the Gephi icon come up, along with this message:

```
(base) michaelduffy@pop-os:~/Tools/gephi-0.9.2/bin$ bash gephi
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory (file:/home/michaelduffy/Tools/gephi-0.9.2/platform/lib/boot.jar) to field java.net.URL.handler
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-lookup.c: 112: check_match: Assertion `version->filename == NULL || ! _dl_name_match_p (version->filename, map)' failed!
(base) michaelduffy@pop-os:~/Tools/gephi-0.9.2/bin$
```

Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: The error you are seeing with JDK 11 or 13 is simply because Gephi is not compatible with Java version newer than Java 8. Curiously, on my machine with the default openjdk-8-jdk package, it seems that i'm able to run Gephi.

Comment: Yes, I understood the point about 11 and 13. The fact that it didn’t run with 8 was odd.